# variable capture in Nginx location matching

Tags: regex, nginx

Let's say I have a URL like this: `www.example.com/a/b/sth`, and I write a location block in Nginx config:

```
location ^~ /a/b/(?<myvar>[a-zA-Z]+) {
    # use variable $myvar here
    if ($myvar = "sth") { ... }
}
```

I hope to be able to use variable `$myvar` captured from the URL *inside* the block, however, Nginx keeps telling me this variable is not defined and won't start:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "myvar" variable
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Because you should try to avoid using `if` -> http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: What stops you from `$1`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Stefano Fratini correctly pointed out in his answer, your `location` declaration has an error: for regular expressions you should use `~` alone, not `^~`.

---

Named captures are a feature of PCRE and they have different syntax available in different versions. For the syntax you use `?<var>` you must have PCRE 7.0 at least.

Please see the extensive information in [official Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

Comment: your link to official documentain points to server_name directive. This does not clarify the use of named captures in other regexp places (location or rewrite directives for example)

Comment: @Perlover it's no different.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov is it no different from trial-and-error, reading the source code, or an assumption? What version of nginx is it no different on? Is it for sure documented, not documented, unknown?

Answer (score 78):

Old thread but I had the same problem...

I think the error isn't related to the PCRE version installed

NGINX doesn't parse your regex if your location tag doesn't start with ~
You need to use something like this

```
location ~ ^/a/b/(?<myvar>[a-zA-Z]+) {
   # use variable $myvar here
   if ($myvar = "sth") { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

^~  is not regex match, it stands longest matching prefix. 
you should use ~ or ~* (case insenstive)  instead

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but the correct way to capture a block into a named variable using PCRE is (?P). So your example misses the P.

Comment: That's only true in older versions of PCRE. Newer versions allow using just the question mark.

Comment: @cliff.wells Unless you're going to state an exact version split, your remark is true for 2014 for certain. But this answer was given in 2012, with default nginx versions in distributions dating back to 1.2/1.3. I'm not so sure (?<var>) was incorporated into those versions. All docs at the time certainly referenced the P.