# Nginx location alias with dynamic parameter

Tags: nginx, location, alias

I'm trying to route a specific URL to another folder in my application root, which I can do with this:

```
location /verify {
  alias /var/www/app/webroot/vue-dist;
  index index.html
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

The above routes **example.com/verify** to its correct folder just fine. However, I'm having trouble adding a dynamic variable to the end.

For example, I'm trying to append an ID to the end of that: **example.com/verify/yDWaAzF4qqy**. I've tried this without any luck:

```
location ~ ^/verify/(?<id>.*)$
```

I'm not super familiar with Nginx and how it handles regex so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Syntax looks OK, you should be able to capture and use `$id` variable in your `location {}` block, and it seems to be not reserved by nginx. Also this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706658/variable-capture-in-nginx-location-matching

Comment: I'm trying to send anything with /verify or /verify/{:id} to that folder; I'm not trying to do any conditional routing with it through Nginx based on that ID. What I've tried so far results in a 404 error.

Comment: @KeithPetrillo What is wrong with your first prefix location? Every request starting with `/verify` (maybe except the asset requests) will be served with your `/var/www/app/webroot/vue-dist/index.html`, isn't that what you actually need? What are you trying to do with the `$id` variable, how are you going to use it?